# Selected value in drodown menu not to change after submit?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

```
<form  method="post">
            <select name="for">
            <option value="-1">A</option>
            ....
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

When the submit button is clicked the selected value goes back the default value. Is it possible for the selected value to stay the same after submit?

Comment: What is the server side technology that you are using?  The only client side way of doing this is by cookies or has tags in the url.

Comment: You can do it with a server-side language (PHP, C# etc.) and set `selected` attribute to selected value on page post-back.

Answer (score 1):

Only with HTML I think it's not possible, you should somehow maintain the selected value and selected it again in the html render, or, you could use a postback with ajax.